# Sci fi short story: crew of an exploration ship doesn't know if Earth actually exists or is a product of their imagination

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short sci fi story a long time ago, as part of a book which contained a bunch of classic science fiction stores (including *Nine Billion Names of God*).

The story was about an exploration spacecraft that left Earth long time ago and the crew was trying to figure out if the life on Earth they remembered was just their imagination and that in fact Earth doesn’t really exist, just the spacecraft and the crew on board.

Comment: The list of anthologies that The Nine Billion Names of God has appeared in [can be seen on the ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41108). It's a long list though.

Comment: To give us a steer on when abouts you read this, approximately how long ago is "a long time ago"?

Comment: Not really enough to base an answer on, but Heinlein's "Universe" meets a lot of the criteria and is a classic in its own right.  (The story was expanded into the novel "Orphans of the Sky".)  Do you remember "Muties", an abbreviated/corrupted word for both Mutants and Mutineers being a part of the story?